# Python Multiprocessing Streamhandler

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, python-3.4

I have the following code (this is just a a part of it, reduced( i know its still a lot) for sake of SO)

**NOTE: OS in use - Windows 7**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count, freeze_support
import os, sys, logging, math, argparse
from filechunkio import FileChunkIO

def _upload_for_multipart(keyname, offset, multipart, part_num, bytes):
    exec_file = os.path.abspath( sys.argv[0] )
    exec_dir = os.path.dirname( exec_file )
    default_logger = dict( pdir=exec_dir, ldir='logs', lname='s3_cli.log', level='INFO',
                               fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s' )

    logger = _get_logger( **default_logger )
    try:
        if multipart.id:
            with FileChunkIO(keyname, 'r', offset=offset, bytes=bytes) as fp:
                logger.info('Start uploading part #%d ...' % part_num )

                #multipart.upload_part_from_file( fp=fp, part_num=part_num )
                logger.info('Uploading part')
        logger.info( 'UPLOADED part #%d' % part_num )

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error( 'FAILED uploading part #%d' % part_num )
        raise

def multipart_upload(bucketname, keyname, **kwargs):
    file_path = keyname
    file_name = os.path.basename(keyname)
    source_size = os.stat(file_name).st_size

    bytes_per_chunk = 10485760
    mp = ''
    chunk_amount = int(math.ceil(source_size / float(bytes_per_chunk)))
    parallel_processes = 1

    #mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload( keyname )
    logger.info('Starting multi upload')    
    chunk_amount = int(math.ceil(source_size / float(bytes_per_chunk))) 
    logger.info ( 'File Upload begininning with {0} cores'.format( parallel_processes ) )
    pool = Pool(processes=parallel_processes)
    for i in range( chunk_amount ):
        offset = i * bytes_per_chunk
        remaining_bytes = source_size - offset
        bytes = min( [bytes_per_chunk, remaining_bytes] )
        part_num = i + 1
        pool.apply_async( _upload_for_multipart, [keyname, offset, mp, part_num, bytes] )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def _get_logger( pdir, ldir, lname, level, fmt ):
    try:
        logs_dir = os.path.join( pdir, ldir )
        if not os.path.exists( logs_dir ):
            os.makedirs( logs_dir )
    except Exception as e:
        print ('{}'.format(e))
        exit(1)

    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=os.path.join(logs_dir, lname),
        level=level,
        format=fmt
    )
    return logging.getLogger( lname )

if __name__=="__main__":
    freeze_support()
    default_bucket = ''
    exec_file = os.path.abspath( sys.argv[0] )
    exec_dir = os.path.dirname( exec_file )
    default_logger = dict( pdir=exec_dir, ldir='logs', lname='s3_cli.log', level='INFO',
                               fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s' )
    logger = _get_logger(**default_logger)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description="CLI." )
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument( "-v", "--verbose", action='store_const', const=True, help="Output process messages to stdout \
                            channel")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    logger = _get_logger(**default_logger)

    if args.verbose:
        try:
            print_handler = logging.StreamHandler( sys.stdout )
            print_handler.setLevel( logging.DEBUG )
            formatter = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
            print_handler.setFormatter( formatter )
            logger.addHandler( print_handler )
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
    multipart_upload(default_bucket, 'large_testfile.log', cores = 6  )
```

What i am trying to do is to log the childprocess statements  to the log file.
I have been successfull and the log file has the logs I am looking for. However this is part of a CLI and 
i have a `-v` `(verbose)` argument which is basically streaming the log file
to the terminal. Even with the when i do `python test.py -v` there is no output to the terminal. I am very new to
the logging module so I dont fully understand the whole module. what am I doing wrong here. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: why is there similar code under `if__name__..` and your `_upload_for_multipart` ?

Comment: @letsc - The child process cant pull objects , varibales out of the global scope...Thats why I have repeating code